# How can I prove that DEF is an equilateral triangle?

Tags: triangles

TRIANGLE ABC IS EQUILATERAL AND

I drawed the picture fast but, AD=BE=CF

[image]

([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK8Zk.png))

With this information I should be able to prove that DEF is an equilateral triangle.
Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Is $\triangle ABC$ equilateral?

Comment: There's too much to guess at here.  Are we meant to assume that the segments which look perpendicular, are in fact perpendicular?

Comment: Is △ABC equilateral? yes △ABC is indeed equilateral.
The angles of these triangles aren't perpendicular at any point, that must have been my mistake with drawing it in paint.

Comment: Are you sure?  $\overline {DF}$ sure looks perpendicular to $\overline {AB}$....and if I assume those internal segments are in fact perpendicular to the sides of the original triangle, then it is easy to prove what you want.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, but it is in fact my mistake with drawing it this way. The inner triangle should have been turned a few degrees to the left. 
But let's assume you are right with the perpendicular part. How would you continue from this point?

Comment: I posted a general solution below, you don't need perpendicularity.

Comment: If $\Delta ABC$ is equilateral, then please mention this in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the original triangle is equilateral we see that the segments $\overline {DB},\overline {EC},\overline {AF}$ are all congruent.  Thus the three triangles $\Delta DBA,\Delta ECF,\Delta FAD$ are congruent (By Side-Angle-Side) and we are done.

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot!

Comment: I donot understand

Comment: @superbjhon  Can you be more specific?  The triangle $\Delta ABC$ is equilateral so the vertex angles at $A,B,C$ are all equal.

Comment: He never mentioned that ABC is equlateral

Comment: See my solution

Comment: @superbjhon  Ah, but he did.  In the comments.  I agree that it ought to be stated explicitly in the post (though, to be fair, he did say that the three sidelengths were equal).

Comment: I am not going to read all comments and then how will i know

Comment: @superbjhon  Take this up with the OP!  As I say, though, he did say that the three sidelengths were equal, so unless you are objecting that he nowhere specified that apparently collinear points were actually collinear, I do believe he said enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough. What about the other segments of the outer triangle sides, like $DB$?

Your drawing suggests that $ABC$ is a triangle as are $DBE$ and so on, but you have to state this as condition, if you do not want your reader to cherry pick what he likes best from the sketch.

Comment: hmm, I might have forgotten to say that ABC is a equilateral triangle.
Can't I just say that because AD=BE=CF that DB=AD=CF, those must be equal aswell right? and now we've got 2 out of 3 sides of the 3 triangles.
so the last 3 must be equal to eachother aswell. am I right?

Comment: @Hithere Yes, but you'd also need to note the included angles are congruent.

Comment: Ah i see, and by the angles you mean the angles of A, B and C? 
So that we've got 1 angle and two sides. and the last side is now proven to be the same at all three places

Answer (score 0):

I am  sure this is incomplete

More information is needed

[image: see the solution]

Only if ABC IS EQUILATERAL IT IS POSSIBLE.

If it is equlateral

we see rhat

The three triangles $\Delta DBA,\Delta ECF,\Delta FAD$ are congruent (By Side-Angle-Side) and we are done.

Comment: Yes @superb jhon you are correct. It has been solved now. ABC is equilateral and I will explain it here for you:
The original triangle ABC is equilateral. DB=EC=AF are congruent.
So now we've got 3 angles (ABC,BCA and CAB) which are all three the same, and we've got 2 sides. So this is Side-Angle-Side. We have now proven that DEF = equilateral

Comment: You nevet told ABC IS equlateral brother

Comment: You are right, I haven't stated it in the question, my mistake. 
Thanks a lot for your time though!! 
We can lock this question up now

Comment: Wow i dont even get a upvote for a effort

Comment: You did get my upvote haha, but I haven't got over 15 rep at the moment. So it is saved but not displayed or something? 
I am new here so I am not entirely sure how it works yet

Comment: Wow thats cruel